# Using Pre-processor Macro,how to change file name for Development, staging and production Environment?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

**Problem statement:-** I am using third party library, which need to have config.plist(name must be same), Config.plist have several key-value pairs, for production,Dev and stating environment, values for key does change.
Right now i need to manually change file Name, like if i need to run app in production environment, i do change file name ConfigPROD.plist into Config.plist,
for Staging i do change file name from ConfigDev.plist into Config.plist.

**Need Solution like:-** can i change, file content using preprocessor macro, like

```
    #if isProductionBuild == 1
    #define kBaseURL @"https://api.base.com/bart/"
    #define kEnvironmnet @"PROD"
    ***//copy ConfigPROD.plist file content into Config.plist***

#elif isStageBuild == 1
    #define kBaseURL @"https://api-stage.base.com/bart/"
    #define kEnvironmnet @"stg"
     *//copy ConfigSTG.plist file content into Config.plist*
#else
    #define kBaseURL @"https://api-dev.base.com/bart/"
    #define kEnvironmnet @"dev"
     *//copy ConfigDEV.plist file content into Config.plist*
#endif
```

pleae see if we do have feature like "copy ConfigDEV.plist file content into Config.plist"

**Note:-** This file copy operation should get completed before third party library start using Config.plist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a preprocessor macro, you need a **Run Script** build phase that gets executed first. See [Running a Script While Building a Product](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaRunScriptBuildPhase.html) for an introduction. Just create a Bash script that looks at `$CONFIGURATION` (which will be *Debug* or *Release* or any other configuration name you have) and then renames one or the other file. Something like:

```
mv ./Config.plist ./Config.plist.orig
if [[ 'Release' == ${CONFIGURATION} ]]; then
    cp ./Config.PROD.plist ./Config.plist
else
    cp ./Config.DEV.plist ./Config.plist
```

To easily handle this, add all 3 files (`Config.plist`, `Config.DEV.plist` and `Config.PROD.plist`) to Xcode, but **only the first one** should be added to the target (check the box in the right side panel). You can have default settings in this file, it will be overwritten anyway.

If you're using **git** or something similar, you can add another run script phase at the end of your build to restore the original `Config.plist` to hide your changes from git.

Comment: thanks for help, can we get value of macro in shell script like isProductionBuild  set to 1. if possible please do write working code.

Comment: No, you can't get macro values in the script. Use the **name of the configuration** to determine whether this is a production build or not.